# Two-tier PKI without OCSP?

Tags: windows, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

I am currently in the planning phase of a two tier Windows PKI using [this deployment guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15037.ad-cs-step-by-step-guide-two-tier-pki-hierarchy-deployment.aspx), and I am stuck concerning the use of OCSP and the online responder role of ADCS.

The guide mandates that one of the servers act as the HTTP CDP/AIA location and be configured as an online responder with OCSP. This role requires the datacenter edition of Windows Server. This is not an option for me due to cost, and I am not sure how to argument the deployment. Do I have to cut out the HTTP CDP/AIA location altogether and rely solely on LDAP, or is there another way to configure it?

My experience with ADCS so far has been with simple, single-tier enterprise root CA's, so this has been a learning process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use Server 2012 Standard

The [edition requirements for OCSP have been removed in Windows Server 2012](http://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/windows-server-2012-rc-active-directory-certificate-services-features.aspx).